# One process returns more than one PID

Tags: batch-file

I am using this batch file to find process names via their PID values:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET /a pid=4792
FOR /f "skip=3delims=" %%a IN ('tasklist') DO (
    SET "found=%%a"
    SET /a foundpid=!found:~26,8!
    IF %pid%==!foundpid! echo found %pid%=!found:~0,24%!
)
GOTO :EOF
```

In return I see this output:

```
root@root: C:\Users\root\Desktop\PIDf.bat
found 3276=svchost.exe

root@root: C:\Users\root\Desktop\PIDf.bat
found 4792=svchost.exe
```

Shouldn't one process never have more than one PID?

Am I missing something here?

Comment: It is only _PIDs_ that are unique. Multiple processes may exist for a given executable such as `svchost.exe`, and all these processes report their name as that of the underlying executable.

Comment: TIP: `FOR /F "TOKENS=1,2 DELIMS=," %%G IN ('tasklist /NH /FO CSV') DO`  That will assign the Image Name to %%G and the PID to %%H.

Comment: You can even take the `TASKLIST` command a bit further to list only the `PID` you want. `tasklist /NH /FO CSV /FI "PID eq 4792"`.

Answer (score 2):

A process can be run multiple times, and hence will appear in Task manager, or here via your script, with different process IDs.

So this is perfectly valid.

In fact, SVCHOST.exe is used to run all kinds of Windows services as it acts as a host (the clue is in the name!).